# Setting variable with more than two conditions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

First time dealing with this so please bare with me.

I inherited a web application that handles three different environments but shares the same code base. Essentially, it's three different web applications rolled into one - with minor to major adjustments on each environment.

I'm launching the site and the CSS and JS paths linked need to change, to take into account a new domain folder.

I found a variable called 'DOMAINBASE', and some variables above it - please see the code below:

```
export const isEnvironmentBFE:boolean = checkEnvironment(DEPLOY_ENV.BFE);
export const isEnvironmentTCAT:boolean = checkEnvironment(DEPLOY_ENV.TCAT);
export const isEnvironmentBFERENTAL:boolean = checkEnvironment(DEPLOY_ENV.BFERENTAL);

export const DOMAINBASE = checkEnvironment(DEPLOY_ENV.BFE)
  ? "https://subdomain.domain1.ca"
  : "https://subdomain.domain2.com";
```

I want to add another condition, in other words another URL to DOMAINBASE, where there is currently only two.

I've tried adding the following condition but does not work:

```
export const DOMAINBASE = checkEnvironment(DEPLOY_ENV.BFE)
  ? "https://subdomain.domain1.ca"
  : checkEnvironment(DEPLOY_ENV.BFERENTAL) // <-- when new environment is launched
  ? "https://subdomain.domain1.ca/new-folder" // <-- make it so it uses this structure
  : "https://subdomain.domain2.com";
```

How do I properly add a third condition to this JavaScript variable?

Comment: Your code seems to work for me -- what specifically isn't working? You might also want to make sure that `checkEnvironment` is returning the right thing. Also, instead of using those `checkEnvironment` calls again, you should probably also use the const variables from earlier (isEnvironmentBFE, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps try it without the 'export'?
This is working for me when i try from the console

```
    const DOMAINBASE = 5<6
      ? "https://subdomain.domain1.ca"
      : 6<7 
      ? "https://subdomain.domain1.ca/new-folder" 
      : "https://subdomain.domain2.com";
```